# VBA Help Comparing Lists and adding to one

Tags: vba, excel

forgive the ugly code, I'm trying to check if a value from sheet 1 exists in a list on sheet 2 and if it doesn't add it to the list on sheet 2, I have managed to do this for one column (A) but i would like to do it for the row from A:K instead; I have managed to make this work for A and could index match the rest but I really don't want to and its annoying that I cant make this work

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheet1 
Set sh2 = Sheet2
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & lr)
For Each c In rng
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh2.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2) = c.Value
End If
Next
```

Comment: This is awesome, I have  never used the resize, but it works a treat. Does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the statement

```
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2) = c.Value
```

by resizing the source and destination ranges to be 1 row x 11 columns wide, so that it becomes:

```
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)(2).Resize(1, 11).Value = c.Resize(1, 11).Value
```

---

Personally, I don't like using the `(2)` part of that, so I would actually use

```
sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Resize(1, 11).Value = c.Resize(1, 11).Value
```